# How Do I Add Many2One Data In Files

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have a few interdependent models with Many2One and One2Many relations in between them.

I have the views all set up but now that I'm adding data through data files to test everything I find that I have no idea how to go about adding these records.

Should I do a run where I basically declare the records while keeping relation values null then update the records with relations later?

Additionally, what's the value of a relational field supposed to be? An array or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the demo and data files of builtin modules as reference

as you can see [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/hr/hr_demo.xml#L141) `category_ids` is is `Many2many` field (same applies for `one2many` fields)

`<field name="category_ids" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('employee_category_2')])]"/>`

to understand the value of the `eval` attribute read the following:

```
(0, 0,  { values })    link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
(1, ID, { values })    update the linked record with id = ID (write *values* on it)
(2, ID)                remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
(3, ID)                cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
(4, ID)                link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
(5)                    unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
(6, 0, [IDs])          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)
```

and for the `ref` function in it's value ( i.e this part `ref('employee_category_2')` ) it's a `python` function evaluated when the data file is loaded, it takes the XML recordID of the related field ( sometimes you might need to use external ID - for example in this case the external id of the record is `hr.employee_category_2`)

**References: [1](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/set-value-for-a-many2many-field-from-data-xml-file-103041) [2](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-insert-value-to-a-one2many-field-in-table-with-create-method-28714)**

Comment: and for `Many2one` fields you just need to use `ref('XMLID')` as a value for the `eval` attribute of `field` XML element, just as you do when you refer to inherited view in `inherited_id` attribute in view definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll be trying to create base records all at once then adding records via (6, 0, [IDs])